# Determining the value of a loop control variable after the loop in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have the following program:

```
program example
implicit none
integer::i, x1
real::x(10)=0
do i=10,1,-2
  x(10-i)=2*i+1
enddo
x1=i*2-1
end program example
```

My problem is to determine the value of `x1` but since variable `i` was never input or specified, how does Fortran determine the value of `i` used in the calculation of `x1`?

Answer (score 3):

*"since variable `i` was never input or specified"*

This assumption is wrong. Inside the loop `i` takes exactly defined values 10, 8, 6, 4, 2.

After the loop finishes, the Fortran standard specifies that the value of `i` shall be the next value of the loop counter as if the loop still continued, so the value of `i` will be `0`.

So the value of `x1` will be 0*2 - 1 = -1 and it can be easily verified by adding `print *, x1` at the end of the program.

---

But there is a different problem with your program as francescalus found out. On the first iteration the value of `i` is 10 and you are accessing  `x(10-i)` which is `x(0)`. This element does not exist, `x` has only elements from `x(1)` to `x(10)` so accessing `x(0)` is illegal and the behaviour of the whole program after that point is undefined.

Comment: Fair enough, yes, the program as the whole becomes invalid. I have actually played with the code, but never enabled bounds checking thinking the code is too trivial.