# Fortran do loop not calculating the entered variable

Tags: fortran, do-loops

When I run the code for Celsius only I am getting the result below the code:

```
    program temperature
! F C temperature conversion
implicit none
real :: celcius=0.0, fahrenheit=0.0

integer:: t,n
print *,'enter the number of lines'
read*, n
do n=1,n
print*,'enter the  value of t: one per line',n
read*, t
celcius=5/9*(t-32)

enddo
do n=1,n
print*, t, celcius
enddo
end program
```

result

```
    enter the number of lines
3
 enter the  value of t: one per line           1
50
 enter the  value of t: one per line           2
20
 enter the  value of t: one per line           3
10
          10   0.00000000E+00
          10   0.00000000E+00
          10   0.00000000E+00
          10   0.00000000E+00
```

It's clear that compiler is not picking the value of `t` in the calculation.

Comment: Only the last value entered in the first loop provides the value for `t` outside the loop.  If you want to use multiple values you should use an array, or restructure the rest around the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three problems:

1. The expression `5/9*(t-32)` is evaluated left-to-right, so the `5/9` part is an *integer* (truncating) division, always producing 0.  The product of zero with anything finite is zero.  There are several ways you could address that, but one of the simpler would be to rewrite the expressions as `5 * (t - 32) / 9`.
2. Your variables `t` and `celcius` are scalars.  They hold only one number at a time each.  In your first loop you assign multiple values to each of them them in sequence.  When you later perform a second loop to print the results, only the last value assigned to each variable will be accessible.  If you must defer output until after reading all the input then one way to handle it would be to make `t` and `celcius` arrays of sufficient size, and store your values in different elements.  (Also note: the correct spelling of the English word is "celsius".)
3. Per @albert in comments, after an indexed `do` loop finishes, the value of the iteration variable is the one it would have had in the next iteration of the loop, if there were one.  Therefore, by using variable `n` both as your iteration variable and your upper bound, you are causing its value to be different after each loop than it was before.  There are several ways you could address this, but I urge you to simply avoid reusing `n` as your iteration variable.  There is no efficiency to be gained by avoiding a for-purpose iteration variable.

Comment: so without using array here i wont be able to view result in a table form? i am sorry i know its a silly question but i am trying understand how array and loops work

Comment: I think there is even a more serious problem: `do n=1,n`, i.e. redefining the value of `n`

Comment: That's an interesting observation, @albert, mainly because it is surprisingly *wrong*.  In a conforming Fortran implementation, the number of iterations of an indexed `do` loop is computed (as if) before entry into the loop.  Therefore, if the upper bound is given by a variable and that variable is modified during execution of the loop, including if it is used as the iteration variable, the number of iterations is not affected.  Indeed, you can see the effect of that in the output reported by the OP.

Comment: You can especially see that in the first loop the initial `n` has the value 3 and in the second loop the initial `n` has the value 4 (not 100% sure but I think that actually the value of a loop counter at the end of a loop is implementation dependent).

Comment: Yes, @albert, I was just writing an addendum about that.  I disagree that it constitutes a "more serious" problem, but it does need to be addressed, and I will shortly update this answer to talk about that.  But there is no uncertainty about the value of the iteration variable after the loop; see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211598/2402272.

Comment: @mangesh, if you want to read all the inputs first before producing any output, then you need to store at least the inputs, *somewhere*, until you've collected them all.  An array would be the easiest way, but it's not the only way.  For example, you could write them to a temporary file and then read them back when you're ready to process them.  A single scalar variable does not suffice, as I've already said.

Comment: I remember I asked this above point before on this site .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166126/upper-bounds-of-fortran-do-loops

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1. Store the input in an array and process the array.

   ```
   program temperature
     ! F C temperature conversion
     implicit none

     real, allocatable :: fahrenheit(:)
     integer:: n

     print *,'enter the number of lines'
     read*, n
     allocate(fahrenheit(n))
     print*,'enter the  value of t: all items on one line'
     read*, fahrenheit
     print *, 'F: ', fahrenheit
     print *, 'C:', fahrenheit_to_celcius(fahrenheit)

   contains

     pure elemental function fahrenheit_to_celcius(t_f) result(t_c)
       real, intent(in) :: t_f
       real :: t_c

       t_c = 5.*(t_f-32.)/9.

     end function fahrenheit_to_celcius

   end program
   ```
2. Process the inputs one at a time

   ```
   program temperature
     ! F C temperature conversion
     implicit none

     real :: fahrenheit
     integer:: i, n

     print *,'enter the number of lines'
     read*, n

     do i = 1, n
        print*,'enter the  value of t: one per line',n
        read*, fahrenheit
        print *, 'F: ', fahrenheit, 'C:', fahrenheit_to_celcius(fahrenheit)
     enddo

   contains

     pure elemental function fahrenheit_to_celcius(t_f) result(t_c)
       real, intent(in) :: t_f
       real :: t_c

       t_c = 5.*(t_f-32.)/9.

     end function fahrenheit_to_celcius

   end program
   ```

Note that I have used the elemental keyword for the function. It means that you can pass a scalar as well as an array. This is a nice solution for direct computations such as the one here: the routine `fahrenheit_to_celcius` is identical in both cases.

I fixed the `5/9` (that returns 0) and the mixed up variables as well.

Comment: hi thanks for the help....i had managed to get the results as you suggested in the 2nd method but couldn't get the out put in the table form which i presume is possible with arrays as of now since i haven't got as far as the last block in your code with function

Comment: By "in table form", do you mean subsequent lines with first the temperature in C then in F? If so, just loop over the output array in the first example as follows: `do i = 1, n` `print *, fahrenheit(i), fahrenheit_to_celcius(fahrenheit(i))` `end do`. Put these in subsequent lines and do not forget to declare the variable i as `integer :: i`.